# How to Tell When Azure Remove-AzureStorageShare Is Done In PowerShell

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I am trying to perform a scheduled operation where I create a file share in Azure and copy some files in it.  Before I begin doing so, I would like to cleanup the previous job if it did not cleanup on the prior run.  To do so, I found the handy-dandy `Remove-AzureStorageShare` method.  My problem is that after I call this method, it takes Azure sometimes up to 2 minutes to complete the task.  I have a wait in PowerShell, but I'm unable to check Azure for the share without throwing an exception and then continue.  So basically, I want the following operations to happen:

1] Check for Share in Azure, delete if it exists
2] Once Azure is done deleting, re-create it
3] Copy my files into the new Share

Here is what I have and it doesn't work:

```
Write-Host "STEP  6 : Removing existing Azure Share...";  
# THIS NEXT LINE THROWS AN ERROR IF THE SHARE DOESN'T EXIST
If ((Get-AzureStorageShare -Name $azureShareName -Context $context) {
    Remove-AzureStorageShare 
       -Context $context 
       -Name $azureShareName 
       -Force 
       -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null  
}  

$removed = $false;

While(!$removed) {
    Try {
        # THIS LINE SHOULD THROW AN EXCEPTION SINCE IT'S BEING DELETED
        If ((Get-AzureStorageShare -Name $azureShareName -Context $context) -eq $null) {   
            $removed = $true;
        }
    }
    Catch
    {
        # SINCE THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN, WE WILL SLEEP FOR A FEW...
        Write-Host "STEP 6a : Waiting...still removing.";
        Start-Sleep -s 10;
    }
}
```

When I attempt to create the share again, I get the following error:

`New-AzureStorageShare : The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. HTTP Status Code: 409 - HTTP Error Message: The specified share is being deleted. Try operation later.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your question.
I think we can use this PowerShell to check for share in Azure:

```
Write-Host "STEP  6 : Removing existing Azure Share...";  
# THIS NEXT LINE THROWS AN ERROR IF THE SHARE DOESN'T EXIST
If ((Get-AzureStorageShare -Name $azureShareName -Context $ctx)) {
Remove-AzureStorageShare `
      -Context $ctx `
      -Name $azureShareName `
      -Force `
      -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null  
    }      
$removed = $false;
While(!$removed) {
Try {
     # THIS LINE SHOULD THROW AN EXCEPTION SINCE IT'S BEING DELETED
    If ((Get-AzureStorageShare -Name $azureShareName -Context $ctx) -eq $null) {   
                $removed = $true;                             
        }

     else {
          Write-Host "STEP 6a : Waiting...still removing.";
          Start-Sleep -s 5;
           }
   }
Catch
                   {
            # SINCE THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN, WE WILL SLEEP FOR A FEW...
            Write-Host "STEP 6b : Waiting...still removing.";
            Start-Sleep -s 5;
        }
    }
```

If the Share existing the PowerShell will show: waiting…still removing, else the PowerShell will show error 404:
[image]

If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.